# MongoDB with NextJS/Vercel - just one dev session creates hundreds of ever increasing connections

Tags: mongodb, next.js, vercel

I'm running a nextjs app on vercel, with mongo linked in the nextjs api folder. I'm just running one dev session with minimal usage, but the number of connections in mongo keeps doing up, often past 300 connections. Why is it causing so many connections and how can I limit this?

```
//lib/mongoClient.ts
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'


const options = { maxPoolSize: 20 }

let dbclient
let clientPromise

  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  dbclient = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI as string, options)
  clientPromise = dbclient.connect()


// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise
```

examples of how I initiate it:

```
//api/posts/fetch.ts
import clientpromise from '../../../lib/mongoClient';



export default async function handler(req, res) {
  
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { username } = req.body;

   
    const client = await clientpromise;
           const db = client.db();
        const posts = await db.collection('posts').find({username:username}).sort({ date: -1 }).toArray();
```

another example:

```
//api/plans/edit.ts

import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import clientpromise from '../../../lib/mongoClient';


export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { planid, desc } = req.body;

    try {
      const client = await clientpromise;
      const plans = client.db().collection('plans');
      
      await plans.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: new ObjectId(planid) },
        { $set: { desc } },
        { returnOriginal: false }
      )
```

Here's a screenshot of the connections graph in mongo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWbZv.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in development mode, where you are running `next dev` on Vercel on your development branch, you are using Hot Module Replacement to create new clients each time there is a reload.

Your MongoClient.ts file looks like you removed all the development env settings, since the comments are still the standard ones you get with [example project](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/lib/mongodb.ts).

You need to utilize [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) to create a single client that is preserved across reloads.

This is the full example:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  let globalWithMongo = global as typeof globalThis & {
    _mongoClientPromise?: Promise<MongoClient>
  }

  if (!globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
    globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
  }
  clientPromise = globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
  clientPromise = client.connect()
}
```

This is common to most database client connections and learning this pattern will solve problems in the future.